# Clustering with MapKit using Xcode 8+ and Swift 3+

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, mapkit

I'm trying to use a third party solution for clustering annotations with MapKit.

I found this pod Cluster - https://github.com/efremidze/Cluster that seems to be for Swift 3.

Their example runs ok and I followed their guide for installations but I'm coming up with numerous errors.

Error ClusterManager has no member 'zoomLevel'

```
        manager.zoomLevel = 17
```

Error Value of type Annotation has no member 'type'

```
        annotation.type = .color(color, radius: 25)
```

Error Extra argument 'visibleMapRect' in call

```
    manager.reload(mapView, visibleMapRect: mapView.visibleMapRect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed `Cluster (1.0.5)`, that's why the error is shown. Please update your pod using `pod update` command or install  `Cluster 1.0.6`

Comment: thanks @mahipal.  i just did a pod install wonder why my version was cluster 1.0.2?

Comment: we need to update our pod after installation. so that any commit on git will pull again. same thing here..

Answer (score 0):

copy all files from "Sources" downloaded with demo, into your project